# Android development for different screens

Tags: android, screen

I need every picture that I have in my program to be created for different densities (mdpi, ldpi, hdpi)? If yes, which density has to be for hdpi? Which one for ldpi?

And the second question. What I don`t understand, that what about screen sizes? What people usually do for support of tablets? They do not do anything with images, they just creating different layouts (which is more convenient)? Am I right or I do not understand?

It would be good to read something besides official documentation. Something that was written in language which is more human.

Thank you.

Comment: Please read [this article](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) - it explains everything you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use 9-patch for some of you img. for example - backgrounds.
but actually - yes, you need images in 4-size

Proportion are:

```
mdpi= *4; 
ldpi= *3; 
hdpi= *6; 
xhdpi= *8.
```

So if you have image mdpi 24*24 px, you must make it 36*36 px for hdpi

And some good resourse http://www.androidguys.com/2010/02/18/handling-multiple-screen-sizes-part-2/

Comment: What do yuo mean by *4, *3, etc. You mean that if mdpi 24*24 we have to add one third of it for hdpi? I think no, couse you wrote *6. Or you just mean the last digit? I last digit then why what is the rule? (why 36, but not 56?)

Comment: We have image in mdpi which is 24px and proportion, which I write above. 

So 24/(4mdpi) =6   Then 6 * (6hdpi) = 36

Answer (score 1):

commonly using just hdip images.(or xhdip)

but if u need correct size, make images for other densities

for tablets, need high resolution images.